# Make a proper JSON string without using json_encode

Tags: php, json, validation

First, here is some backgroung : my current company's servers use old versions of PHP (It's not an option to upgrade it) and json functions are not supported. The company made its own framework with a dedicated function but it seems that the returned string is not always a valid JSON string. I had a parsing error on a SQL request due to indent.
Here is our function :

```
function arrayToJSON ($array) {

    $parts = array();
    $is_list = false;
    if ( is_array($array) && !$array ) return '[]' ;

    //Find out if the given array is a numerical array
    $keys = array_keys($array);
    $max_length = count($array)-1;
    if(($keys[0] === 0) and ($keys[$max_length] === $max_length)) {//See if the first key is 0 and last key is length - 1
        $is_list = true;
        for($i=0; $i<count($keys); $i++) { //See if each key correspondes to its position
            if($i != $keys[$i]) { //A key fails at position check.
                $is_list = false; //It is an associative array.
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
        if(is_array($value)) { //Custom handling for arrays
            if($is_list) $parts[] = arrayToJSON($value); /* :RECURSION: */
            else $parts[] = '"' . $key . '":' . arrayToJSON($value); /* :RECURSION: */
        } else {
            $str = '';
            if(!$is_list) $str = '"' . $key . '":';

            //Custom handling for multiple data types
            if(is_int($value) || is_float($value)){
                 $str .= $value; //Numbers
            }elseif($value === false){
                 $str .= 'false'; //The booleans
            }elseif($value === true){
                 $str .= 'true';
            }elseif(is_object($value)){
                $str .= '"' . '"';
            }else{
                 $str .= '"' . str_replace(array('\\', '"',"\r\n","\n"),array('\\\\', '\\"',' ',' '),$value) . '"'; //All other things
            }

            $parts[] = $str;
        }
    }
    $json = implode(',',$parts);

    if($is_list) return '[' . $json . ']';//Return numerical JSON
    return '{' . $json . '}';//Return associative JSON
}
```

[Here is the parsing error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJkgI.png)

And here is my JS quickfix to it :

```
version = JSON.parse(request.response.replace (/([\s]{4})|[\t]/g, `\\t`)).version;
```

The workaround I made is to replace multiple spaces with \t but I would like to make the function work properly.
So my question is : was the parsing error due to this function or does it come from something else I may have missed ? And how could I make things go right ?

Comment: Which PHP version do you use? Maybe you can get it from PECL? https://pecl.php.net/package/json

Comment: If it's possible, I'd prefer to just patch the function. I'm waiting to talk about it with the team in charge of our system improvments but I'm pretty sure that adding a new library/upgrading won't be aknowledged :/

Comment: If you are using a version of PHP that old, then it won't have had a security update in *years* and **needs** updating.

Comment: I can't think of any situation where indenting will change valid JSON to invalid JSON.

Comment: Don't know (Otherwise, I wouldn't be here asking :D), added parsing error and quickfix.

Comment: There's gotta be proper, vetted, tested JSON encoders compatible with your version written in pure PHP which you could include as a library…?

Comment: Yes, there are but I'd like not to add any library and I'd like to understand why it doesn't work properly :)

Comment: All possible arguments to the contrary, @Quentin is right: An unsupported version of PHP has absolutely no place in production. Since that's not likely to matter, though: I understand not wanting to add dependencies, but in this case, you're still adding one -- a brand new one with no community or support, and with you as the maintainer. The only reasonable approach here is finding a JSON handling library that works with your PHP version. It's good to want to understand what's going on, but not at the cost of the quality of your application.

Comment: You're absolutely right but unfortunately, I've no control over the decisions taken by the company nor the team in charge of the maintainity. My current goal is to eventually come up with a fix and present it to the team that could do something about it :/

Comment: Can you show us some input data and the actual JSON produced by your code. P.S. a site like https://jsonlint.com will tell you if the output is valid or not if you paste it in, and also give you an idea of where the error might be.

Comment: P.S. If there are pure PHP JSON encoders out there, why not at least study how they work (the source code will be readable, since it's PHP). Depending on the license, maybe you can "fork" them to make your own version (of course it will not need many changes!) which you can then include in your application. Meanwhile as others have said, whoever is blocking the upgrade of PHP needs to take a long hard look at whether the reasons for doing so are really justified, because they're just leaving themselves open to known security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Nevermind, the Company just decided to upgrade the PHP version... Thanks to all of you anyway !